# Using interactive sort on subreport closes the subreport

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a subreport with interactive sorting enabled. When clicking on this sort in my subreport from the main report the subreport closes. When I open the subreport it´s sorted as wanted but the need to reopen after every sorting is bad user experience. How can I fix this?

Regards Daniel